# Airflow 1.10.6 kubernetes executor over EKS using s3 connection, task pass test but dag run fail

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-pod

I tried:
**- configuring s3 connection from the value.yaml:**

- connections:

  - id: aws_default
    type: aws
    login: xxxaws_access_key_idxxx
    password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxaws_secret_access_keyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  - id: my_s3
    type: s3
    login: xxxaws_access_key_idxxx
    password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxaws_secret_access_keyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

2. write DAG that uses the s3Hook and write string to s3.
3. run test from scheduler pod:
   /entrypoint airflow test dag_id task_id date_before_the_start_data_of_DAG
4. the file is created and content is ok
5. @ Airflow UI activating the
   DAG and RUN it is queued and fail.
   any suggestions?

**BTW DAG ARGS:**

```
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'trigger_rule': 'dummy',
    #'pool': 'my_workers_pool',
    'catchup': False, # dont fill back
}
```

[image: dag tree view]

[image: clicking the viewlog at UI shows nothing]

in addition I added 5 min sleep to the task that cause the DAG to fail and watched the pod creation at the kubectl but the task started for few seconds and disappears. any Ideas how to debug this issue?

> logs from task pod:
>
> > kubectl logs postgressexamplesababaegozimpostgress-7322d44cb2684a09bef95ad3080b9505
> > -n airflow-research-p-8482f --tail=200 [2020-08-24 12:04:44,262] {{settings.py:252}} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool
> > settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=1
> > /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py:144:
> > UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release
> > 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use  "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see:
> > http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi.
> > """) [2020-08-24 12:04:44,833] {{**init**.py:51}} INFO - Using
> > executor LocalExecutor [2020-08-24 12:04:44,834] {{dagbag.py:92}} INFO
>
> - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/postgress_example.py Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in 
>   [2020-08-24 12:04:44,841] {{dagbag.py:207}} ERROR - Failed to import:
>   /usr/local/airflow/dags/postgress_example.py Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py",
>   line 204, in process_file
>   m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
>   module = _load(spec)   File "", line 696, in _load   File "", line 677, in
>   _load_unlocked   File "", line 728, in exec_module   File "", line 219,
>   in _call_with_frames_removed   File
>   "/usr/local/airflow/dags/postgress_example.py", line 33, in 
>   import boto3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
>   args.func(args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line
>   74, in wrapper
>   return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 529,
>   in run
>   dag = get_dag(args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 148,
>   in get_dag
>   'parse.'.format(args.dag_id)) airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: postgress_example. Either the dag did not
>   exist or it failed to parse.

Comment: what does the log says?

Comment: no logs at the UI and there are massive logging  at the scheduler includes:
running tail -f logs/scheduler/latest/s3hook.py.log (s3hook.py is includes dag) prints:
[2020-08-18 10:04:46,453] {{scheduler_job.py:440}} INFO - Skipping SLA check for <DAG: postgress_examples3> because no tasks in DAG have SLAs <BR>
[2020-08-18 10:04:46,455] {{scheduler_job.py:161}} INFO - Processing /usr/local/airflow/dags/s3hook.py took 0.105 seconds<BR>
[2020-08-18 10:04:48,368] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2020-08-18 10:04:48,368] {{settings.py:252}} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool .....etc

Comment: please include logs in question. (specifically if there are errors in it)

Comment: except {{scheduler_job.py:440}} INFO - Skipping SLA check for <DAG: postgress_examples3> because no tasks in DAG have SLAs
nothing is special

Comment: ok I could get the log of the pod errors are attached in description, I think that the scheduler pod installs the requirement.txt but the worker pod doesn't any ideas? @A.B can you help ?